# webDriver.WindowHandles does not contain all pages

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I've been worked with selenium Web Driver + C# automating my test cases. However, I realized that my automation doesn't work in some environments with same configuration of mine. When I run my code:

```
foreach (var winHandle in webDriver.WindowHandles)
{...}
```

I can found all loaded pages in my browser,but somehow, this code does not work in others computers.

Environment:
* Selenium web Driver
* C#
* Internet Explorer 11

Is there any reason for that?

Comment: We are struggling with the same issue on some computers after upgrading to [Windows 10 Anniversary Update Redstone 1
10.0.14393 · VERSION 1607](http://changewindows.org/build/14393). Strange to say, this issue shows up only on some computers, but not all.

Comment: Is it a timing issue? Have you tried waiting for the number of handles to change or put a break point on that line and waited for the new window to appear and then check the count?

Comment: Yes JeffC, I tried both ways, but unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: krokodilko that's a very weird issue man.